# How can I boot OpenSolaris x86 into single-user mode?

Tags: solaris, system-administration, root, boot

Modern OpenSolaris is configured to disallow root logins during normal boots. It is only possible in single-user mode. However, many instructions online simply say to add "-s" to the end of the default grub boot arguments, which leaves a graphical boot progress display in an endless loop and never enters the single-user mode console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key point left out of many OpenSolaris single-user boot instructions is that you must modify a *text boot* grub entry, and not the default *graphical* entry. Booting in graphical mode with the single-user switch leaves the boot progress graphic overlayed atop the console forever, never allowing the maintenance console to be visible.

- Reboot.
- At the grub prompt, highlight the most recent `text boot` entry and press '`e`'.
- Highlight the line beginning with `kernel$` and press '`e`'.
- Add '`-s`' to the end of the line.

e.g. change:

```
kernel$ /platform/i86pc/kernel/$ISADIR/unix -Bv$ZFS-BOOTFS
```

to

```
kernel$ /platform/i86pc/kernel/$ISADIR/unix -Bv$ZFS-BOOTFS -s
```

- Press '`enter`'.
- Press '`b`' to boot.

The system should boot *without* a graphical overlay, and should promptly arrive at the system maintenance console.

Answer (score 0):

Full solution of OpenIndiana 157:

1. Reboot
2. At the grub prompt, highlight the most recent text boot entry and press 'e'.
3. Remove three lines (pressing d with cursor on the line to be deleted):
   splashimage /boot/solaris.xpm
   foreground d25f00
   background 115d93
4. Press e with cursor on the line beginning with kernel$
5. Remove portion " ,console=graphics" from this line
6. Add ' -s' to the end of this line
7. Press 'enter'.
8. Press 'b' to boot.